# How do I get the Custom X Values on the Chart Areas when I use my mouse on the chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, linechart

I am making a chart on reports and my problem is how can I get the x values(Custom Values of Chart Areas) of my chart when I move my mouse on the chart(annotation)?

I already did this for the past 2 days and I still don't get on how should I get the x values of the chart. I tried using the codes related on charts but I still don't get the desired result

```
Private Sub cmdGenChart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGenChart.Click
    Access.AddParam("@dt1", DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(-1).ToString)
    Access.AddParam("@dt2", DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString)

    Access.ExecQuery("SELECT [Flood_ID], [Flood_Level], [Flood_Time], [Flood_Date] " & _
                     "FROM WaterLevel " & _
                     "WHERE [Flood_Date] BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt2 " & _
                     "ORDER BY [Flood_ID] ASC")

    Dim checkDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value

    For Each r As DataRow In Access.dt.Rows

        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(Counter - 1, Counter + 1, r("Flood_Time"))

        Chart1.Series("Water Level").Points.AddXY(Counter, r("Flood_Level"))

        Counter += 1
    Next

    Dim PC As New CalloutAnnotation

    With PC
        Chart1.Annotations.Add(PC)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Chart1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseMove

    Dim result As HitTestResult = Chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

    If result.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
        Chart1.Series(0).Points(result.PointIndex).XValue.ToString()

        Dim thisPt As New PointF(CSng(Chart1.Series(0).Points(result.PointIndex).XValue),
                               CSng(Chart1.Series(0).Points(result.PointIndex).YValues(0)))

        Dim ta As New CalloutAnnotation

        With ta
            .AnchorDataPoint = Chart1.Series(0).Points(result.PointIndex)
            .Text = "Water Level: " & thisPt.Y.ToString & vbCrLf & "Time: " & DateTime.FromOADate(thisPt.X).ToShortTimeString

            If thisPt.Y.ToString <= 20 And thisPt.Y Then
                .ForeColor = Color.Green
                .Font = New Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            ElseIf thisPt.Y.ToString <= 60 Then
                .ForeColor = Color.Orange
                .Font = New Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            ElseIf thisPt.Y.ToString > 60 Then
                .ForeColor = Color.Red
                .Font = New Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            End If

        End With

        Chart1.Annotations(0) = ta
        Chart1.Invalidate()
    End If
End Sub
```

What I want is that the value of Time is equal to the value of the corresponding x value below it.

On the image:
Water Level: 15
Time: 12:00 AM

Desired Result:
Water Level: 15
Time: 6:21 AM

http://prntscr.com/m0p4xb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many thinking, the solution I found is to set my counter to be equal to the value of my primary keys on the database and set it that it will be bonded on the chart then I will only load it on my SQL commands and that did the trick.

Global variable

```
    Dim counter as Double = 1
```

The generate chart button

```
Private Sub cmdGenChart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGenChart.Click
    Access.AddParam("@dt1", DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(-1).ToString)
    Access.AddParam("@dt2", DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString)


    Access.ExecQuery("SELECT [Flood_ID], [Flood_Level], [Flood_Time], [Flood_Date] " & _
                     "FROM WaterLevel " & _
                     "WHERE [Flood_Date] BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt2 " & _
                     "ORDER BY [Flood_ID] ASC")

    For Each r As DataRow In Access.dt.Rows

        Counter = r("Flood_ID")

        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(Counter - 1, Counter + 1, r("Flood_Time"))

        Chart1.Series("Water Level").Points.AddXY(Counter, r("Flood_Level"))

        Counter += 1
    Next

    Dim PC As New CalloutAnnotation

    With PC
        Chart1.Annotations.Add(PC)
    End With

End Sub
```

The chart mouse move

```
Private Sub Chart1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseMove

    Dim result As HitTestResult = Chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

    If result.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
        Chart1.Series(0).Points(result.PointIndex).XValue.ToString()

        Access.AddParam("@pos", Chart1.Series(0).Points(result.PointIndex).XValue)
        Access.AddParam("@level", Chart1.Series(0).Points(result.PointIndex).YValues(0))

        Access.ExecQuery("SELECT [Flood_ID], [Flood_Level], [Flood_Time] " & _
                         "FROM WaterLevel " & _
                         "WHERE [Flood_ID] = @pos AND [Flood_Level] = @level ")

        Dim r As DataRow = Access.dt.Rows(0)

        Dim ta As New CalloutAnnotation

        With ta
            .AnchorDataPoint = Chart1.Series(0).Points(result.PointIndex)
            .Text = "Water Level: " & r("Flood_Level") & vbCrLf & "Time: " & r("Flood_Time")

        End With

        Chart1.Annotations(0) = ta
        Chart1.Invalidate()
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the result:
http://prntscr.com/m2xpnf